# how can I get a quick count of the number of scenarios and steps in a large cucumber suite without running every test?

Tags: ruby, cucumber

I've tried `cucumber --dry-run`, but it only seems to work on a per feature file basis.

Comment: I'm not sure if this is even *theoretically* possible, as Ruby can do things like generate tests automatically. In order to know how many there are, you basically have to run the suite.

Comment: trust me, the people that wrote these tests have not written tests that generate tests. also, it's not really practical in any business situation to use cucumber that way. I'm not quite sure what you're saying, but it does sound interesting.

Comment: I'm not saying that you've made use of that feature, but since it is possible, which includes things like walling off parts of your tests with `if (false)`, there's no way Cucumber can produce an honest answer without actually executing the tests.

Comment: Are you sure that `--dry-run` only works on a single feature file basis? I just tried and it seems to run against all feature files (assuming a specific file is not specified).

Comment: no. not sure. I just tried it in a rake task, and it's possible I did something wrong. Did it give you the number of features and scenarios? If so, mark yours as an answer, and I'll accept it.

Comment: I see what you're saying, @tadman. Thanks for pointing those possibilities out.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`cucumber --dry-run` will include the count of scenarios and steps for all features run.

For example,

Given two feature files:

test.feature:

```
Feature: 1

    Scenario: 1a
    Given step 1
    Given step 2

    Scenario: 1b
    Given step 1
    Given step 2
```

test2.feature:

```
Feature: 2

    Scenario: 2
    Given step 1
```

When `cucumber --dry-run` is run, the results show:

```
3 scenarios (3 skipped)
5 steps (5 skipped)
```

As you can see, the scenario and step counts are including all scenarios from all features.