# To get total number of features and scenarios from JavaScript test automation project

Tags: javascript, automation, protractor, cucumber, cucumberjs

I am using protractor-cucumber-framework for my test automation. I have multiple feature files. Each feature file has multiple scenarios. I am using "cucumber-html-reporter" to get HTML report of test execution. This HTML report gives detail information about total number of features and total number of scenarios that was executed. So after test execution only I come to know 'total number of feature files' and 'total number of Scenarios' that I was executed.

Is there any command OR plugin available to get

- Total number of features
- Total number of scenarios in each feature file

In my JavaScript test automation ?

Comment: Have a look at this -- http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18004326/how-can-i-get-a-quick-count-of-the-number-of-scenarios-and-steps-in-a-large-cucu

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A versatile JS script for that involves parsing the feature files using Gherkin to a AST and count Features, Scenarios, Tags, etc.. from that structure:

eg:

```
const glob = require('glob')
const Gherkin = require('gherkin')
const parser = new Gherkin.Parser()

const AST = glob
        .sync('./specifications/**/*.feature')
        .map(path => parser.parse(fs.readFileSync(path).toString()))
```

From there you can traverse the AST object and extract features/scenarios counts and all other information needed.

Answer (score 2):

This is quite simple to achieve without plugins.

Why not create an object with the feature names as the key, and the scenario count as the value, and either `console.log()` it, or save it to a file to view later?

I'll show both ways (2.x syntax and 1.x syntax, just so I've covered the bases).

**CucumberJS 2.x Syntax**

```
let {defineSupportCode} = require('cucumber'),
    counter = {};

defineSupportCode(({registerHandler, Before}) => {

    registerHandler('BeforeFeature', function (feature, callback) {
        global.featureName = function () {
            return feature.name;
        };
        callback();
    });

   Before(function (scenario, callback){
        counter[featureName()] !== undefined ? counter[featureName()] += 1 : counter[featureName()] = 1;
        callback();
   });

   registerHandler('AfterFeatures', function (feature, callback) {
        console.log(JSON.stringify(counter));
        callback();
  });
});
```

**CucumberJS 1.x Syntax**

```
var counter = {};

module.exports = function () {

    this.BeforeFeature(function (feature, callback) {
        global.featureName = function () {
            return feature.name;
        };
        callback();
    });

   this.Before(function (scenario, callback){
        counter[featureName()] !== undefined ? counter[featureName()] += 1 : counter[featureName()] = 1;
        callback();
   });

   this.AfterFeatures(function (feature, callback) {
        console.log(JSON.stringify(counter));
        callback();
  });
};
```

**Extra**

If you want to save this to a file, so that you can see it at a later stage, I recommend using the fs-extra library. In place of the `console.log()`, use this:

```
fs = require('fs-extra');
fs.writeFileSync("path/to/file.js","let suite = " + JSON.stringify(counter));
```

Please note, the file will be created from where you ran the the tests.

```
Given I am running from "frameworks/cucumberjs"
When I generate a file from "frameworks/cucumberjs/hooks/counter.js" with the fs library at "./file.js"
Then the file "frameworks/cucumberjs/file.js" should exist

Given I am running from "frameworks/cucumberjs"
When I generate a file from "frameworks/cucumberjs/features/support/hooks/counter.js" with the fs library at "./hello/file.js"
Then the file "frameworks/cucumberjs/hello/file.js" should exist
```

Just make sure that you are running from the right directory.

**Total Number of Features**

If you want the total number of features as well:

In place of the `console.log()`:

```
console.log(JSON.stringify(counter) + "\nFeature Count: " + Object.keys(counter).length)
```

And in place of the writeFile:

```
fs.writeFileSync("path/to/file.js","let suite = " + JSON.stringify(counter) + ", featureCount = " + Object.keys(counter).length);
```

As we have got the scenario count sorted by each feature name, stating the amount of keys within the object we have created will give us the count of the number of features.

Comment: Faims - Thank you so much for the detail explanation